# How does actually arduino measure voltage?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, electronics, analog

I am not interested into the AnalogRead() part, but rather on how he converts 5 or 2 V into a number between 0 and 1023. How does it practically do it to convert the voltage level into a number or into bits to then send to the processor? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATmega328P features a 10-bit successive approximation ADC. The ADC is connected to an 8-channel Analog Multiplexer.

[image: ADC schematic]

First, an input is selected from the multiplexer on the left. This allows any of 8 input channels to be active at one time (but only one). These are: A0 to A5 on the Uno (some boards also have A6 and A7). There are also additional input channels (not shown) which also allows the selection of:

- The internal temperature sensor
- Ground
- Bandgap reference voltage

The input channel (multiplexer output) is connected to a "sample and hold" capacitor, as shown. Once an analog conversion starts the switch is opened after 1.5 ADC cycles (12 µs with the default prescaler of 128) so that the capacitor retains its current reading (ie. it holds it) so that the input voltage can now change without affecting the result. This would be useful for fast-changing signals, as the whole conversion can take 104 µs (depending on the prescaler).

To work out the voltage the logic applies the analog reference voltage (ARef) divided down by a DAC (digital-to-analog converter) under the control of the ADC logic. The output of the DAC is sent to the comparator which determines if the input voltage is higher or lower than the reference voltage, at its current divided state. For example, the high-order bit would be set or cleared by setting the DAC to divide the reference voltage by 2 (ie. 2.5V if ARef is 5V). If the input is higher than 2.5V then the high-order bit in the result is set. This takes one ADC cycle (8 µs at the default prescaler of 128 with a 16 MHz processor clock).

To get the next result bit the DAC would be set to the next step (ie. 0.25 of ARef or 0.75 of ARef depending on whether the first bit was set or not) and another comparison done. This process is repeated for all 10 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno is powered by an ATmega328P microcontroller. According
to [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf#G3.1738665):

> The ATmega48A/PA/88A/PA/168A/PA/328/P features a 10-bit successive
> approximation ADC.

On the next page, you can see the following schematic, where I have
highlighted the most essential parts of the converter. You can see the
DAC, the comparator, and the SAR data register.

[image: Schematic of the ADC of the ATmega328P]

If you want to get into the details of how this works, see the Wikipedia
article on [Successive-approximation ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive-approximation_ADC). You may notice the
schematic at the top of that Wikipedia page is somewhat similar to the
one above.